# How to include biblatex \nocite authors in authors index

Tags: biblatex, citing, indexing

Occasionally using `biblatex` I want to reference an authored work (i) without including a formal citation in the text, while (ii) including the work in the bibliography, *and* (iii) including all of the work's authors in the citations [author] index, each of these entries back-referring to the page in which the non-citation reference is included.

I can achieve (i) and (ii) using `\nocite` in the standard way. However, `\nocite` doesn't accomplish (iii). At the moment, I am manually entering possibly multiple `\index[author]{...}` commands with each `\nocite` where I want this behavior to appear, but find this tedious and error prone, especially when non-cited works include large numbers of authors.

Any ideas how I can configure `\nocite` or another suitable command to include option for behaving in the standard way while also including each of the work's authors in the citations index?

Comment: @jon - probably not for two reasons. The citation key `#1` is most unlikely to be the full author name as it appears in the Bibliography and therefore as to appear in the author citations index. Also, the solution will generally need to handle cases of references to documents produced by multiple authors (your suggestion assumes references produced by one and only one author).

Comment: While your overall issue is quite understandable without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), it could be beneficial to still add a compilable example document so people can test their solutions with your set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new "cite" command that only starts the indexing routine

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nociteindex}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}}
  {}
  {}
```

It will print nothing, but it will send the work to the bibliography and index. This solution also indexes the title, if you only want the name, go with

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nociteindex}
  {}
  {\indexnames{labelname}}
  {}
  {}
```

Comment: Genius @moewe! I would never have imagined such an elegant solution. I'm very, very grateful to you!